# Spring Boot App as .war is running, but endpoint is not working

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I built a Spring Boot Rest API and want it to run in a Tomcat container on a Linux server.

- I have a server on [digitalocean](https://cloud.digitalocean.com) running on Ubuntu 20.4
- I installed tomcat as described in this [article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/) and it is running
- I build a very small Spring Boot Application with only one endpoint, which I want to build and deploy on the tomcat server. You can see the build.gradle file here in my github repository: [spring-boot-example](https://github.com/Apri34/spring-boot-example)

Here are some Code Snippets:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello-world")
    public ResponseEntity<String> helloWorld() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world");
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ExampleApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class);
    }
}
```

This is basically the whole app

Steps taken:

- building the war file with './gradlew war' or './gradlew bootWar' locally on my machine (I tried both, i don't know if it makes any difference, but I had the issue with both of them)
- Opening the tomcat manager remotely on `http://'host':8080/manager/html`
- Deploying the .war file manually and waiting until it's deployed:
  [image: Click 'Deploy']
- As you can see, it is up and running:
  [image]
- Now I open the following URL: `http://host:8080/spring-boot-example/hello-world`, where I expect to see the message `Hello world`, as defined in the Controller
- But all I can see is this
  [image: Missing endpoint]

Did I miss something? It says at the end `or is not willing to disclose that one exists`, do I have to do something with that endpoint to make it available to the public? Or did I upload the app incorrectly?

Comment: Can you look in Tomcat's logs? They should tell you if your Spring Boot application started successfully.

Comment: What is your project structure? controller might not get picked up

Comment: @AndyWilkinson How can I do that? Like where can I see the logs?

Comment: @Antoniossss when I run it locally on my machine a, it works. So it should get picked up